# Upscale 2D low-res images

Tags: java, swing, jframe, image-resizing

I am using the program [ImageResizer](https://code.google.com/p/2dimagefilter/) with the XBR4x algorithm to upscale .gif images from an old 2D game from 32x32 to 48x48.

The exact procedure:

1. Manually rename all images to .jpeg because the program wont open .gif
2. Resize the images, they are saved by the program as .bmp
3. Manually rename the images to .gif again.

The problem:

When looking at the images in Paint they look very good, when drawn in my RGB BufferedImage they suddenly all have a white/grey ~1px border which is not the Background Color, the images are placed directly next to each other. As I have a whole mosaic of those images the white borders are a no go.

Image 32x32: [image]

Image 48x48 after upscaling: [image]

Ingame screenshot of 4 of those earth images with white borders: [image]

The question:

How do those borders originate? And if not possible to answer this, are there more reliable methods of upscaling low resolution game images making them look less pixelated?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: do you *rename* images or *convert* them? would also be nice if you had a sample image before and after resizing attached to the question.

Comment: Summing all up, the problem seems most likely to arise from the fact that algorithms like xBr or hqx can only do x2, x3, etc. enlargement and not x1,5. So the program seems to do some presizing with the image, leading to those white borders.

Comment: Why not just resize the images using a graphics 'editor' like e.g. Gimp (big, but free).

Comment: Because Gimp and other such programs do only have ugly and very basic upscaling algorithms. The best I know is [Kopf-Lischinski](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kopf/pixelart/paper/pixel.pdf) but sadly isnt out for public yet. xBR though comes close to it so I want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emailed Hawkynt, the developer of the tool and it seems the error is not in the tool but in Microsofts implementation and he fixed it (actually even bigger tools like Multiple Image Resizer .NET have the problem). This is what he said about his program:

"When you entered width and/or height manually, the image got resized by the chosen algorithm where everything went fine.

Afterwards I used the resample command from GDI+ which implements a Microsoft version of the bicubic resize algorithm.
This implementation is flawed, so it produces one pixel on the left and upper side for images under 300px.

I fixed it by simply making the resized image one pixel larger than wanted and shifting it to the left and up one pixel, so the white border is no longer visible and the target image hast he expected dimensions."

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an artifact of the image resizing algorithm, the borders are actually visible one the upscaled image before it is combined, if you look at them in XnView, for example.
The best way to fix that would be to use another tool to resize the image, one which allows the user to control such borderline effects, but if you have to use this one you could still work around the problem by constructing a 3x3 grid of the original image (which would be 96x96), scaling it up to 144x144 and then cutting out the central 48x48 piece. This would eliminate the borderline effects.

Comment: Sorry, cannot suggest one right away, but I guess you should look for a tool originally designed for *textures*, rather than photos or other sorts of images.

Answer (score 1):

The border is a result of a scaling procedure performed by the mentioned tool. Consider this demo that shows tiles based on scaled image from the question and scaled image created using [Image.getScaledInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

Note that if you choose to stay with your own scaling method check out [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html) for more optimized solutions.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestImageScale {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY2i8.gif"));
            Image scaled = original.getScaledInstance(48, 48,
                    Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
            BufferedImage scaledOP = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Argxi.png"));

            BufferedImage tilesOP = buildTiles(scaledOP, 3, 3);
            BufferedImage tiles = buildTiles(scaled, 3, 3);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tilesOP)));
            panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(tiles)));

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel,
                    "Tiles: OP vs getScaledInstance",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Failure",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static BufferedImage buildTiles(Image tile, int rows, int columns) {

        int width = tile.getWidth(null);
        int height = tile.getHeight(null);

        BufferedImage dest = GraphicsEnvironment
                .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .getDefaultConfiguration()
                .createCompatibleImage(width * rows, height * columns,
                        Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics g = dest.getGraphics();
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
                g.drawImage(tile, row * width, col * width, null);
            }
        }

        g.dispose();

        return dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you put in the answer. If there is no program I can find to do some upscaling I will use this method. But I'd really like to scale them with a nice algorithm before runtime. Do you maybe know one or should I make a new question for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: Do the original images have an Alpha channel (or do you implicitly create one when resizing)? When resizing an image with alpha, the scaling process may assume the area outside the image to be transparent and the border pixels may become partially transparent, too.

Comment: The original images dont hava an Alpha channel but I just saw the output images have one.